# Why replace function return index of even numbers?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm trying to replace *underscore* `_` by its number of occurrence?

```
'_,_,_,_'.replace(/_/g,(x,i)=>i)
'0,2,4,6'
```

***expected output:*** `'0,1,2,3'`

Comment: the commas have the odd indexes.

Comment: So, i is the index of char underscore in string

Comment: Your `i` parameter [is the offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement), not the iteration index. You should probably introduce your own counter.

Comment: How can I get number of it instead index of it! like the expected output?

Comment: @Ivar is there a possibilty of doing it with regex or I'll do with for-loop approach?

Comment: `let i=0;'_,_,_,_'.replace(/_/g, _ => i++);` is a hacky way to achieve this

Comment: `i = 0; /* ... */ .replace(/_/g,() => i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox) for answer: `i=0,'_,_,_,_'.replaceAll(/_/g, _ => i++);//'0,2,4,6'`

Comment: (it was more of a suggestion than an answer  - glad it helps)

Comment: Any way; it Gets The Job Done!